# How to display Russian characters using Unicodes?

Tags: android, unicode, localization

I am new to Android.I have prepared one application for display Russian characters using Unicodes. unicodes for Russian i got from this site,

```
http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm
```

My code is,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append("\u1040");
 tv.setText(sb.toString());
```

It is working fine.But it is showing like BOX.How to over come this.Please help me.

Comment: Do you know if you have the fonts installed to display Russian characters?

Comment: \u1040 is not cyrillic letter. Googling founds it is "Unicode Character 'MYANMAR DIGIT ZERO' (U+1040)" Maybe \u0410 and others.

Comment: ya \u0410 is correct for A Russian character

Comment: @user1336049 look at the code you have above, you are using `\u1040`.

Comment: after changed from \u1040 to \u0410 it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

@Deucalion pointed it out first, but you meant to put "\u0410" instead of "\u1040".